# how to Unzip slx file

Tags: c#, simulink, unzip

I want to extract files from slx folder.

I used this :

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(myStream))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
        e.Extract(TargetDirectory);
    }
}
```

It works with a zipFile.

I have the following error :

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMjQ2.png)

What can I do?

Comment: Please post the error message (in English) here

Comment: The file C:\Desktop\metadata\coreProperties.xml already exists.             "An error has occurred while opening project file:{0}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message should answer your question:
You are trying to extract a file which is already there -> use a different/new folder as `TargetDirectory` and it should work.